# numpy blit (copy part of an array to another one with a different size)

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I want to copy one array to another one with a different size.
I would like a function like this:

```
blit(destimg,src,dstlocation)
```

for example `blit(zeros((7,7)),ones((3,3)),(4,4))`

would result in

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

The top left center of array `src` is now in the location `(4,4)` of the array `destimg`.

if I did `blit(zeros((7,7)),ones((3,3)),(5,5))` I would get:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

The array `src` doesn't fit in the `destimg` but its top left corner is still in the right position.

Comment: Can't you achieve what you want with a simple assignment (i.e. the `=` operator) and using proper indexing?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I can but for the cases where the src array doesn't fit I would have to make some computations to figure out the proper indexing. I was wondering if numpy had already a function for that.

Comment: Why isn't your ```blit``` function sufficient?

Comment: That is, the entire or only portions of the destination array get replaced by the entire source array or only portions of the source array. So, the problem boils down to finding the indices, right. Does this need to work with 2D arrays only? Or should it work for n dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just compute the appropriate slices:

```
import numpy as np

def blit(dest, src, loc):
    pos = [i if i >= 0 else None for i in loc]
    neg = [-i if i < 0 else None for i in loc]
    target = dest[[slice(i,None) for i in pos]]
    src = src[[slice(i, j) for i,j in zip(neg, target.shape)]]
    target[[slice(None, i) for i in src.shape]] = src
    return dest

print(blit(np.zeros((7,7)), np.ones((3,3)), (5, 5)))
```

yields

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

and

```
print(blit(np.zeros((7,7)), np.ones((3,3)), (-1, -1)))
```

yields

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution (a bit verbose), there must be a more elegant way but in the mid-time this will do.

```
from numpy import *

def blit(dest, src, loc):
    th,tw=dest.shape
    sh,sw=src.shape
    sr = 0 if -loc[0]<0 else -loc[0]
    fr = sh if loc[0]+sh<=th else sh-(loc[0]+sh-th)
    sc = 0 if -loc[1]<0 else -loc[1]
    fc = sw if loc[1]+sw<=tw else sw-(loc[1]+sw-th)
    loc[0] = max(0,loc[0])
    loc[1] = max(0,loc[1])  
    dest[loc[0]:loc[0]+sh-sr,loc[1]:loc[1]+sw-sc] = src[sr:fr,sc:fc]

dest = zeros((7,7))
src = ones((3,3))
loc = [5,5]
blit(dest, src, loc)
print dest
```

yields:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

and

```
dest = zeros((7,7))
src = ones((3,3))
loc = [-1,-1]
blit(dest, src, loc)
print dest
```

yields

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: As you see, a nicer way is what @unutbu has come up with. You should definitely make use of the fact that sliced indexing on numpy arrays behaves as Python slicing on built-in types, with respect to out-of-bound indices. Quote from Python introduction to strings: "Degenerate slice indices are handled gracefully: an index that is too large is replaced by the string size, an upper bound smaller than the lower bound returns an empty string."

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation:

```
def blit(a, b, offsets=(0,), as_shapes=False):
    """
    Computes the slices of the overlapping regions of arrays <a> and <b>. If offsets are specified, 
    <b> will be shifted by these offsets before computing the overlap.

    Example:
          50
       ┌──────┐
       │      │ 
     65│  ┌───┼────┐
       │  │   │    │50
       └──┼───┘    │
          └────────┘
              55
    <a> is the 65x50 array and <b> is the 50x55 array. The offsets are (32, 18). The returned 
    slices are [32:65, 18:50] for <a> and [0:33, 0:32] for <b>.

    Arrays of different dimensions can be used (e.g. 3-dimensional RGB image and 2-dimensional 
    grayscale image) but the slices will only go up to min(a.ndim, b.ndim). An offset with more 
    elements than that will throw a ValueException.

    Instead of arrays, shapes can be directly passed to the function by setting as_shapes to True.

    :param a: an array object or a tuple is as_shape is True
    :param b: an array object or a tuple is as_shape is True
    :param offsets: a sequence of offsets
    :param as_shapes: if True, <a> and <b> are expected to be array shapes rather than array
    :return: a multidimensional slice for <a> followed by a multidimensional slice for <b>
    """

    # Retrieve and check the array shapes and offset
    if not as_shapes:
        a, b = np.array(a, copy=False), np.array(b, copy=False)
        a_shape, b_shape = a.shape, b.shape
    else:
        a_shape, b_shape = a, b
    n = min(len(a_shape), len(b_shape))
    if n == 0:
        raise ValueError("Cannot overlap with an empty array")
    offsets = tuple(offsets) + (0,) * (n - len(offsets))
    if len(offsets) > n:
        raise ValueError("Offset has more elements than either number of dimensions of the arrays")

    # Compute the slices
    a_slices, b_slices = [], []
    for i, (a_size, b_size, offset) in enumerate(zip(a_shape, b_shape, offsets)):
        a_min = max(0, offset)
        a_max = min(a_size, max(b_size + offset, 0))
        b_min = max(0, -offset)
        b_max = min(b_size, max(a_size - offset, 0))
        a_slices.append(slice(a_min, a_max))
        b_slices.append(slice(b_min, b_max))

    return tuple(a_slices), tuple(b_slices) 

def paste(a, b, offsets=(0,), copy=True):
    """
    Pastes array <b> into array <a> at position <offsets>

    :param a: an array object
    :param b: an array object
    :param offsets: the position in <a> at which <b> is to be pasted
    :param copy: whether to paste <b> in <a> or in a copy of <a>
    :return: either <a> or a copy of <a> with <b> pasted on it
    """

    out = np.array(a, copy=copy)
    a_slice, b_slice = blit(a, b, offsets)
    out[a_slice] = b[b_slice]
    return out
```