# Copy data from one numpy array to an other with possibly missmatched sizes

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

So my issue is that I'm trying to paste a small image into a larger image with the typical numpy syntax :

```
large_im = np.linspace(0,1,20)[:,None]*np.ones([1,20])
small_im = np.linspace(1,0,10)[None,:]*np.ones([10,1])

a0,b0 = 5,5
large_im[a0:a0+small_im.shape[0],b0:b0+small_im.shape[1]] = small_im

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(large_im)
```

[image: typical case]

This works fine most of the time but there are edge cases, where part of the small image hangs outside of the large image and numpy doesn't like it.

Like so :

```
a0,b0 = 15,15
large_im[a0:a0+small_im.shape[0],b0:b0+small_im.shape[1]] = small_im
```

Or :

```
a0,b0 = -5,-5
large_im[a0:a0+small_im.shape[0],b0:b0+small_im.shape[1]] = small_im
```

[image: edge case]
These two snippets raise a Value error because numpy indexing produces a target array that do not match the small_im size.

Right now I have to tediously handle all those edge case by writing a bunch of code that checks each dimension of the source and target area and trims the sizes down so that everything fits properly.

**Do you know if there is a numpy function that does this automagically ?**

Comment: Tediousness is obviously a very subjective matter, but, wouldn't the manual checks just be two `min` and two `max` calls?

Comment: That tediousness is just some numeric bookkeeping, and won't affect the actual copy speed.

Comment: Looks like this question is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676187/numpy-blit-copy-part-of-an-array-to-another-one-with-a-different-size

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
a0,b0 = 15,15

view = large_im[a0 : a0 + small_im.shape[0], b0 : b0 + small_im.shape[1]]

view[:] = small_im[: view.shape[0], : view.shape[1]]

plt.imshow(large_im)
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

It doesn't work when `a0` or `b0` are negative, but you could easly use an `if` statement for those cases:

```
if a0 < 0:
    a0 += large_im.shape[0]

if b0 < 0:
    b0 += large_im.shape[1]
```